# Quotes missing around title of arXiv papers (biblatex + biber)

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, biber

I am using biblatex and biber. Here is a sample LaTeX file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits,style=numeric-comp,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\bibliography{longnames.bib,test.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {Selected Publications}, 
}
\begin{document}

Ref.~\cite{CJS:2013} and~\cite{BCW:2012}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The reference BCW:2012 looks like this in the bib file.

```
@online{BCW:2012,
  author    = {B and
               C and
               W},
  title     = {Musings and machinations},
  eprinttype   = {arXiv},
  eprint    = {1234.5678},
  eprintclass = {cs.DS},
  year      = {2012}
}
```

The problem is that the title "Musings and machinations" doesn't have quotes round it when rendered whereas all other (non-arXiv) papers do.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using biber version 0.9.9.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on 'non-arXiv papers'? Are they also of type `online` or are they `article`-type?

Comment: @JosephWright This is the only online paper. The rest are of type  article and InProceedings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard `biblatex` settings include the lines

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

thus meaning that the `title` field is not put in quotes for online entries. This can be altered uing

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this documented somewhere or just in the source?

Comment: This is in the source. There are simply too many fields/formats to document everything formally: the idea is that the mechanisms to _change_ formatting are documented, so you can rapidly alter things to what you want.

Comment: OK. Well I don't see how I could have solved my particular problem without either reading the source or asking here. Is there a way I am missing?

Comment: @Raphael `\DeclareFieldFormat` is described in the manual, as are `\mkbibquote` and `\isdot`. Reading `biblatex.def` is useful for style changes: it's commented and I think reasonably clear.