# How to make the style of title in @online biblatex non-italic

Tags: biblatex

I have a book with @online biblatex url whose title will be appeared in italic. I want to make it non-italic for @online but for@book italic title is fine. Do you know how to do it?
To run : I run pdfLaTeX first, then Biber then pdfLaTeX again:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
author       = {Herlastname, Herfirstname M},
date         = {2010},
title        = {company for him},
publisher    = {City: publisher},
}
@online{myurl,
author       = {Hislastname, Hisfirstname M.},
date         = {2019},
title        = {company for her},
organization = {Wikibooks},
url          = {https://helping_each_other_and_i_help_u.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
like to see \textcite{mybook} try \citeauthor{myurl}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{#1}`. Search the `biblatex` manual and this site for `\DeclareFieldFormat`, `\DeclareListFormat`, and `\DeclareNameFormat` for lots of examples of how to format fields. Also `biblatex` prefers `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` over `\bibliography{\jobname}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93963/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 and in general https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864.

Comment: @DavidPurton Do you want to type up a quick answer here, or do you want us to close this as a duplicate (maybe of one of the three questions I linked)?

Comment: @moewe is it better to just close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @DavidPurton I found a question that is a pretty good fit, so I closed as a duplicate. But if you'd like to write up an answer we can reopen.

Comment: @moewe, use that golden hammer you have ;)